# Integration based on modulus

Tags: integration

Let $\displaystyle I= \int^{19}_{10} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^8} \, dx$

I have to prove that $|I|<10^{-7}$

MyApproach:

\begin{align}
|I| & = \left|\int^{19}_{10} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^8} \, dx\right| \\[10pt]
& \le \int^{19}_{10} \left| \frac{\sin x}{1+x^8}\right| \, dx
\end{align}

because $|\sin x|\le 1$

$$\le \int^{19}_{10} \frac{1}{|1+x^8|} \, dx$$

Now I can't proceed from here because i don't know the denominator's modulus.
I would be interested to know how to continue solving this problem from my last step.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $|1 + x^8| \ge |x|^8 - 1 \ge 10^8 - 1$

Comment: What's the reason for -1,I included my question,formatted properly and didn't even ask for the whole solution.I only asked about my specific problem.I think I have followed all the rules and regulations provided my mathematics stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

If $10\le x\le 19$ then $1+10^8 \le 1+x^8 \le 1+19^8.$

Therefore $\dfrac 1 {1+10^8} \ge \dfrac 1 {1+x^8} \ge \dfrac 1 {1+19^8},$ and so

$$
(19-10) \cdot \frac 1 {1+10^8} \ge \int_{10}^{19} \frac{dx}{1+x^8}.
$$

Comment: I can't understand your last line.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer : That's just the fact that if $f(x) \le M$ for all values of $x$ and $a<b$ then $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \le M(b-a). \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$I<red<red+blue=\dfrac{19-10}{10^8+1}<\dfrac{10}{10^8}=\dfrac{1}{10^7}$

[image]